# Android round image with custom corners

Tags: android

for rounding image corners there are many library and released, but i want to round custom corners such as only `TopLeft` and `BottomRight` but i cant find this library on Android Arsenal or github. for example see this screen shot

[image]

all of released libraries rounding all corners, and i dont like it

Comment: did you tried it yourselves to tweak some code and have the desired output?

Comment: @KaranMer no sir, i dont try. i'm looking for found library which has this feature

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use such rounded corners (only 2 out of 4), I'd suggest creating `.png` file with corners as you want them, 9patching images to stretch properly and setting created file as background to your layout (CardView, any layout you use...)

Answer (score 0):

Set below xml as background of your main layout of listview raw file.

**corner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

            <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Hope it helps!!!